# PP tense of "become" and an Adj

Tags: adjectives, past-participles, attributive-nouns

In this sentence:
*The Internet has become mission critical for many institutions today.*

1- In the case of *has become*, we should use of *has + PP of the word*. Is the *become* PP of *become*!?
2- Why we didn't use the *critical mission* instead of *mission critical* in the sentence? Are they apart from each other, that is, *mission, critical for...*?

Thanks.

Comment: Any dictionary gives you the basic forms of to become. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/become?q=become

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, *become* is the past participle of *become*. It is exactly like *come*, with *be-* added: I (be)come, I (be)came, I have (be)come.
2. *Mission critical* (often hyphenated, particularly in attributive position, *a mission-critical resource*) is a very common phrase these days. It means *critical to the mission*, i.e. essential in order to accomplish the mission. Your rewrite would miss the sense, implying that the Internet is the mission for these institutions, when in fact the Internet is critical to the various missions these institutions pursue.